# jquery subtotal and grand total using specific td id and key

Tags: jquery, html, cumulative-sum, subtotal

I've tried to figure this out, and I'm a newbie so I appreciate any direction. I've got a script that does inline table editing and it works well. I need to modify it so it will subtotal the rows using only the COST column multiplied by the ORDER QTY column, with the subtotal at the end of the row, and the grand total at the bottom. The problem is that each TD cell does not have an input box unless you click on it and do the inline edit feature, then its gone on save. So I need some kind of innerHTML jquery call to do the math (I think), using the TD attributes available, which are ID and KEY.

So for the first row, I'd need the TD with id="1" key="part_cost" multiplied by the TD with id="1" key="order_qty" and displayed as a subtotal in the TD cell with id="subotal" then grand total at the bottom of the table.

Here's the code I have:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <table class= "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">MODEL</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">PART #</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">SERIAL</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">KIND</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">NAME</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">SIZE</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">SET</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">COST</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">MSRP</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">MIN QTY</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">ACTUAL</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">ORDER QTY</th>
              <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">SUBTOTAL</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="model_id">3</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_num">1</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_serial_num">123123123</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_kind"></td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_name">item1</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_size">size1</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_set">2</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_cost">120</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="part_msrp">0.00</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="min_qty">20</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="actual_qty">0</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="1" key="order_qty">4</td>
              <td id="subtotal"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="model_id">3</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_num">2</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_serial_num">123123321</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_kind">set</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_name">item2</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_size">size2</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_set">1</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_cost">50.00</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="part_msrp">125.00</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="min_qty">15</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="actual_qty">4</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="2" key="order_qty">24</td>
              <td id="subtotal"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="model_id">3</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_num">7</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_serial_num">345123456</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_kind">set</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_name">item3</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_size">size3</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_set">1</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_cost">120.00</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="part_msrp">0.00</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="min_qty">15</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="actual_qty">5</td>
              <td class="xedit" id="3" key="order_qty">7</td>
              <td id="subtotal"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="10"></td>
              <td colspan="2">Grand Total:</td>
              <td><div id="grandTotal"></div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
            $('.xedit').editable();     
            $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
                var key = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('key');
    var x = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('id');
    var y = $('.input-sm').val();
    var z = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().text(y);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+'&key='+key,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(s){
                        if(s == 'status'){
                        $(z).html(y);}
                        if(s == 'error') {
                        alert('Error Processing your Request!');}
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
                    }
                });
            });
    });
    </script> 
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Each `id` should really be unique in your page. You could do something like `<tr class="even" id="1">` or `<td class="xedit 1" …`

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use the "key" value instead?

Comment: `key` isn’t a standard html5 attribute, so it’d be safer to use a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#custom-data-attribute).